# Multi platform build & CI server

Tags: continuous-integration, multiplatform, build-management

we use UrbanCode's AnthillPro build and CI server to build our C++ multi platform applications in a number of environments: linux, windows, solaris, hp-ux and aix. Yes, I know that AnthillPro was initially not designed to build C++ applications - rather for Java applications, but we've managed to make it do what we need :).
Now, UrbanCode belongs to IBM and it looks like they're about to discontinue AnthillPro. That's why we're now looking for an alternative solution.
The key features we appreciate in Anthill / expect to be supported by the new solution:

- support of multiple C/C++ compilers (see above)
- good and efficient dependency management and resolving
- support of JavaC (very important in the future)
- own "artifactory" / Anthill's CodeStation anologon
- work distribution between build stations (Anthill's Agents concept)
- logging and reporting tools (obvoius)

Can anybody recommend a solution, which complies to this feature list? If one or two features are not supported out of the box, but can be implemented with on-board tools or with help of unix' shell and other admin-tools, that's OK!